# debugging css ipad

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile, extjs

I'm create a website specifically for the ipad.  What tools should i use to help me debug CSS?  I'm developing from a desktop environment, but testing and viewing my changes on the iPad.

I use firebug to debug your normal website.  But my ipad website doesn't show up at all in firefox.  It shows up in Safari, but Sencha's drag, touch and slide event handlers don't respond well to my mouse events.

What tool do I use to debug css (and possibly javascript) issues on an ipad website built with Sencha?

Comment: You can also use this iPad app (iDebug for iPad) http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/idebug/id525956537?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D2 this app loads firebug lite on your web page so you can debug javascript and css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using google chrome's developer tools.   It uses the webkit engine just like safari, so it's the closes thing I have.

Comment: Safari also has those developer tools (they actually originated in Safari as part of Webkit), so you could get even closer to iPad's rendering by using that. See: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/safari/developer-tools.html :)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Phantom Limb](http://www.vodori.com/blog/phantom-limb.html).

It simulates touch events on a desktop browser to enable testing. (it also turns your mouse pointer into a giant hand, which I guess adds to the effect.... hmmmm)

This is quite a new thing -- I haven't tried it myself yet; it's still on my 'todo' list, so I can't tell you how great it is, just that it is supposed to solve the kind of problems you're asking about.